# Setting of "Disabled" Property in jQuery Not Working for Touch Event

Tags: jquery, properties, touch, element

For example, a piece of jQuery code:

```
$("#my_button").prop("disabled", true);
```

The code can prevent the button from responding to mouse click events correctly. However the button continues responding to touch events on mobile devices regardless of the setting of "disabled" property.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to completely disable the button or other elements by preventing them from responding to all user interactions. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may `.unbind()` all events listeners

Comment: I noticed that I have used: `$(document).on("touchstart", "#my_button", function(event) {...})` to define the event handler to process touch event on #my_button. Is this form the same as `$("my_button").on("touchstart", function(event) {...})? Can the code `$("my_button").off("touchstart") remove the event handler set by `$(document).on("touchstart", "#my_button", function(event) {...})`? Thx!

Comment: 1. When you use `$(document).on("touchstart", "#my_button", function(event) {...})` event occurs on #my_button element and then bubbles to document element. document handler will be triggered. In second case event occurs on #my_button element and is handling by  #my_button element handler.                                         2. You can't disable handler by doing this `$("my_button").off("touchstart")` because it was registered on document element not on #my_button.